# Xcode 7 beta 2 not compiling code

Tags: swift2, xcode7-beta2

I'm running `Xcode 7 beta 2` and my code won't compile, it won't break on breakpoints when running and it won't throw errors even if I add broken code to it.

When I run my application in the simulator my *old version* of my app runs in the simulator *even* if I **delete** it from the simulators home screen.

This same code base runs perfectly on my macbook pro.

Things I've tried so far:

- cleaning
- rebuilding
- restarting
- uninstalling, re-downloading and reinstalling Xcode

**running on my iMac:** (Xcode 7 beta 2)

[image]

**exact code running on my MacBook Pro** (Xcode 7 beta 2)

[image]

### Has anyone experienced this before? Any solutions?

Comment: Try to clean the project (Build > Clean). And after all, it's beta software

Comment: thanks @ZoffDino, Yes, as mentioned in my OP, I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding. I know its beta software and the behavior of the IDE is not guaranteed. I just posted this question in the off-chance that someone knows of an easy fix... I think I might have to uninstall / reinstall Xcode...

Comment: interesting, reinstalling did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is buggy behavior coming from a beta release of Xcode. The obvious things to try are as follows:

1. Try cleaning and building your project.
2. Try restarting Xcode and repeating the previous point.
3. Reboot your computer.
4. If all else fails reinstall Xcode.

This unfortunately didn't work for me, but here's what did... and it's silly. It may be an edge case but try going to your storyboard and just mess around with some buttons or labels, add a new Image View or delete one... then try building and running. That caused my code to compile.

Comment: I don't want to add this to my answer because it's a theory. A senior developer at my work told me he thinks there may have been an XML parsing error behind the scenes and when I changed my storyboard interface it caused the XML to recompile properly.